# Can multiple breadcrumb trails lead to the same url?

Tags: seo, local-seo, technical-seo

Suppose there is a url to a real estate broker who covers Miami and Orlando.  There will be several  breadcrumb trails to the broker page:

- RE Brokers > Florida > Miami >   John Doe
- RE Brokers > Florida > Orlando > John Doe
- RE Brokers > Florida > John Doe

  There could be n number of trails leading to the same 'Canonical' broker url.    Will this cause   SEO penalty ?

I plan to display only one breadcrumb trail to the end user depending how the user got there.  For example if the user searched brokers in Orlando,  it would show Orlando trail and so on.  However,  the crawler might consider it a conflict?

Comment: How are you going to decide which breadcrumb trail to show if the user didn't get there through any of the breadcrumbs but rather through a bookmark a search engine or some other means?

Comment: Good question.  I modified the question to add 'canonical' url.  So the query parameters have  state and city name which are used to display the breadcrumbs.  The canonical url is  rebrokers/john-doe  and other urls will be  rebrokers/john-doe?state=fl&city=orlando   Thus the user can bookmark any url.

Comment: Keep in mind that adding query parameters creates **new URLs**.  It sounds like you are going to have many URLs which have nearly duplicate content with the only differences being breadcrumbs. Based on your question, I was thinking you were going to change the breadcrumbs based on `referer` header or store history information in the user's session.

Comment: Will having several  duplicate URLs but one canonical url, adversely affect SEO ?   Yes only difference will be  breadcrumbs but it's needed. For example, if a user searches for brokers in Miami, clicks on broker A, it should show  Brokers > FL > Miami > Broker A. If they searched in Orlando, it should how Brokers > FL > Orlando > Broker A.    Breadcrumbs are navigation aid and it's useful to display like this.  What would be an ideal approach ? Just not have the breadcrumbs on the broker page ? but then it misses the original thesis - breadcrumbs are navigation aid.